# Converting an int to a float in C

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion, int

I'm having trouble converting an `int` into a `float`. I tried to type convert but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
float *six(const int *x) {
    float *p = malloc(sizeof(x));
    p = (float *)x;
    return p;
}

int main() {
    float *p_six;
    int i4 = 4, i432 = 432;

    p_six = six(&i4);
    printf("%d == %f\n", i4, *p_six);
    free(p_six);
}
```

Comment: The `p = (float *)x;` assignment in the function obliterates the pointer to the memory allocated in the previous line, so you have a memory leak every time you call the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can't point a `float *` to an `int` and expect it to be interpreted properly.  They have very different representations, so you'll end up with garbage.

All you need to do is assign your `int` value to a `float` and it will be converted.

```
int main()
{
    float f;
    int i = 4;

    f = i;
    printf("%d == %f\n", i, f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4 == 4.000000
```